# How to make different nodes randomly spawn from a set position?

Tags: swift, for-loop, sprite-kit

I have five dice with different number faces. Say I want them to fall from (x: 150, y: 400). How do I make it so that a different faced die will fall each time from that set position? Would a `for i in 0..1` loop be necessary? Willing to post relevant code if needed. Thank you in advance.

```
  class GameScene: SKScene {

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in self.falling()}),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(5.0)])))







    func falling() -> SKSpriteNode {
    let first = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dice")
    first.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)
    first.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(45, 45))
    first.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    first.name = "Die1"

    let positions = [
        CGPointMake(150, 600),
        CGPointMake(300, 600),
        CGPointMake(100, 600),
    ]

    let randomPositionIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(positions.count)))
    first.position = positions[randomPositionIndex]

    first.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

       addChild(first)
    first.runAction(
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -900,
            duration: NSTimeInterval(10.8)))


    return first


}
```

}

Comment: It is always better to include the relevant code which can produce the issue, and to clearly  point out what is the desired output. That way, you have better chances to get your answer. Also, you don't risk being downvoted because questions like this often end up downvoted.